# Injecting an implementation of a generic interface subtype using Guice

Tags: java, generics, dependency-injection, guice

I have the following APIs defined:

```
public interface Input<I> {
    Collection<? extends I> read();
}

public interface Transformer<O, I> {
    Collection<? extends O> transform(Collection<? extends I> inputData);
}

public interface Output<O> {
    void write(Collection<? extends O> output);
}

public interface Executor {
    void execute();
}
```

and the following implementations:

```
public final class InputImpl implements Input<String> {
    @Override
    public Collection<? extends String> read() {
        return asList("1", "2");
    }
}

public final class TransformerImpl implements Transformer<Integer, String> {
    @Override
    public Collection<? extends Integer> transform(final Collection<? extends String> inputData) {
        return inputData.stream().map(Integer::parseInt).collect(Collectors.toList());
    }
}

public final class OutputImpl implements Output<Integer> {
    @Override
    public void write(final Collection<? extends Integer> output) {
        System.out.println(output);
    }
}

public final class ExecutorImpl<I, O> implements Executor {
    private final Input<I> input;
    private final Transformer<O, I> transformer;
    private final Output<O> output;

    @Inject
    public ExecutorImpl(final Input<I> input, final Transformer<O, I> transformer, final Output<O> output) {
        this.input = input;
        this.transformer = transformer;
        this.output = output;
    }

    public void execute() {
        final Collection<? extends I> inputData = input.read();
        final Collection<? extends O> outputData = transformer.transform(inputData);
        output.write(outputData);
    }
}
```

Here is my attempt to bind the APIs to the implementations from above:

```
public final class ModuleImpl extends AbstractModule {
    @Override
    protected void configure() {
        bind(new TypeLiteral<Input<String>>() {
        }).to(InputImpl.class);

        bind(new TypeLiteral<Transformer<Integer, String>>() {
        }).to(TransformerImpl.class);

        bind(new TypeLiteral<Output<Integer>>() {
        }).to(OutputImpl.class);

        bind(Executor.class).to(ExecutorImpl.class);
    }
}
```

When I am trying to get an instance of `Executor` using a Guice injector, I am getting the following errors:

```
1) com.csc.playground.guice.api.Input<I> cannot be used as a key; It is not fully specified.
  at com.csc.playground.guice.ExecutorImpl.<init>(ExecutorImpl.java:25)
  at com.csc.playground.guice.module.ModuleImpl.configure(ModuleImpl.java:33)

2) com.csc.playground.guice.api.Transformer<O, I> cannot be used as a key; It is not fully specified.
  at com.csc.playground.guice.ExecutorImpl.<init>(ExecutorImpl.java:25)
  at com.csc.playground.guice.module.ModuleImpl.configure(ModuleImpl.java:33)

3) com.csc.playground.guice.api.Output<O> cannot be used as a key; It is not fully specified.
  at com.csc.playground.guice.ExecutorImpl.<init>(ExecutorImpl.java:25)
  at com.csc.playground.guice.module.ModuleImpl.configure(ModuleImpl.java:33)
```

Comment: I'm not sure it is possible. For example, what should `injector.getInstance(Executor.class)` inject into `ExecutorImpl`, if you have bound `Output` for several generic parameters? This is perfectly valid in Guice, because type literals will be different.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Conceptually, the problem is here:

```
@Inject
public ExecutorImpl(final Input<I> input,
        final Transformer<O, I> transformer,
        final Output<O> output) {
```

When guice attempts to fulfill the dependency for, say, `Input<I>`, it doesn't know what type it is; that's what "It is not fully specified" means.

You can fix this by specifying what the generic types are. You do this the same way you did the bindings in your `AbstractModule`, e.g instead of binding to `ExecutorImpl.class`, do:

```
bind(Executor.class).to(new TypeLiteral<ExecutorImpl<String, Integer>>() {});
```